# Bootstrap 5 navbar-toggler-icon does not appear

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 within Rails 7 application. I am following Bootstrap's Dashboard example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/dashboard/ but within my Rails application the navbar-toggler-icon is not displaying (nor does it work) when I shorten the width of the browser window.

I have a CodePen example https://codepen.io/chrisgo-cp/pen/zYPpEPp that shows the code I am using and navbar-toggler-icon is not displaying.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 me-0 px-3" href="#">Company name</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu"
          aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Sign out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
              <!-- <span data-feather="home"></span> -->
              Link ?
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <!-- <span data-feather="file"></span> -->
              Link ?
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
          <span>Saved reports</span>
          <a class="link-secondary" href="#" aria-label="Add a new report">
            <!-- <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span> -->
          </a>
        </h6>
        <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <!-- <span data-feather="file-text"></span> -->
              Report 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <!-- <span data-feather="file-text"></span> -->
              Report 2
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <%= yield %>
    </main>

  </div> <!--/ .row -->
</div> <!--/ .container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... Remove `position-absolute` from the `<button>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <header class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 me-0 px-3" href="#">Company name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <div class="nav-item text-nowrap">
        <a class="nav-link px-3" href="#">Sign out</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
        <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                <!-- <span data-feather="home"></span> -->
                Link ?
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <!-- <span data-feather="file"></span> -->
                Link ?
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
            <span>Saved reports</span>
            <a class="link-secondary" href="#" aria-label="Add a new report">
              <!-- <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span> -->
            </a>
          </h6>
          <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <!-- <span data-feather="file-text"></span> -->
                Report 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <!-- <span data-feather="file-text"></span> -->
                Report 2
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
        <%= yield %>
      </main>

    </div>
    <!--/ .row -->
  </div>
  <!--/ .container-fluid -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this code isn't working for me when I go to a full window using the "expand snippet" link, but does work within the smaller "Run Code Snippet".  Do you have any thoughts as to why?  I'm on a Chrome V103 broswer.

Comment: The hamburger is shown only on a smaller screen size by default (you can change the breakpoint). When you click `Run code snippet` the screen size is smaller, but when you click `Full page` the screen size is bigger. Read more about it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I'm just following this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ and Chrome's Responsive Deign Mode to look at small screens, and I never see the button appear. It does show up, invisibly on small screens, as I can tell by hovering when the menu disappears, but it's neither visible not does it show the menu when clicked. You'd think the basic Bootstrap intro would covered these things and maybe just work?

Comment: Hm, it's hard to help without the code. Did you ask a question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If no, ask and let me know so I can answer you (if nobody else will know the solution).